# Is there any difference between UserLocalServiceUtil.addRoleUser and RoleLocalServiceUtil.addUserRole?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In Liferay API, I observed that `UserLocalServiceUtil.addRoleUser(long roleId, long userId)` and `RoleLocalServiceUtil.addUserRole(long userId, long roleId)` are available through two different services for same purpose i.e. **Assign Role to User.** Correct me I am wrong!

Digging further deep into the implementation reveals following hierarchy:

```
UserLocalServiceUtil.addRoleUser > UserLocalServiceBaseImpl.addRoleUser >
RolePersistenceImpl.addUser > TableMapperImpl.addTableMapping (roleToUserTableMapper)
```

(methods accepting two parameters `long roleId`, `long userId`)

While,

```
RoleLocalServiceUtil.addUserRole > RoleLocalServiceBaseImpl.addUserRole >
UserPersistenceImpl.addRole > TableMapperImpl.addTableMapping (userToRoleTableMapper)
```

(methods accepting two parameters `long userId`, `long roleId`)

I noticed that both implementations end up in adding mapping between `roleId` and `userId` and vice-versa.

But, I have following concerns:

1. Do the both APIs result in same, that is assigning of Role to User?
   a. If yes, then why is this duplication / repetition of service?
   b. If not, then what is the difference?
2. Which one is better in sense of performance and accessibility?
3. Which one results run-time, without the restart of the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Parkash Kumar : 
Yes you are right! 
Result are given by both methods are same, they just an add entry in some tables.

Check the **afterPropertiesSet()** method of **UserPersistenceImpl.java** this will affect the *Users_Groups,Users_Orgs,Users_Roles,Users_Teams,Users_UserGroups* tables where as **afterPropertiesSet()** method of **afterPropertiesSet()** *Groups_Roles,Users_Roles* effect that tables.

You'll find the implementation and property will has changed by LiferayDEV, which is used to get handy to developers and entries in some tables.

Both Methods give you same thing which you want to achieve but if you are using RLSU method it'll give you fast result compare to ULSU method.

Comment: I too observed `afterPropertiesSet()` method and noticed affection of relevant tables. But, that's not the point I want to understand.